# Make a C program to copy char array elements from one array to another and don´t have to worry about null character

Tags: c, arrays, string

I want to create a program that copies, element by element, one char array to another but the problem is that, if I don´t introduce in the destination array the null character, the program outputs the correct String + weird characters, so my solution was to iterate through with the length of the String + 1 in order to include the null character, is there any way to iterate with the length of the String without having to worry about the null character? The code is as follows:

```
int copy(char * source, char * destination, unsigned int lengthDestination);

int copy(char * source, char * destination, unsigned int lengthDestination) 
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; source[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        //Count the length of the source array
    }
    if(i + 1 != lengthDestination){ //i + 1 in order to take into account '\0'
       return 1;
    }

    for(int j = 0; j < lengthDestination; j++) {
        destination[j] = source[j];
    }
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    char * source = "Test number 17"; //Length is 15 counting the null character
    unsigned int destinationLength = 15;
    char destination[destinationLength];
    copy(source, destination, destinationLength);
    printf("The String source is: %s\n", source);
    printf("The String destination is: %s\n", destination);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You remembered to allow space for the string terminator but forgot to write it. Before `return 0;` the function should write `destination[j] = '\0';` and some similar fix for the early return, since in `main` the return value from `copy` function is ignored.

Comment: @WeatherVane I might be wrong, but in the for loop where i copy the elements from source to destination, i iterate the length of the string + 1 times, so at the last iteration (index 14 in this case) I copy the null character from source to destination

Comment: Oh mybad. I compiled and ran the program which worked correctly, although the early return and non-checking its value still apply. Back to the question, why don't you simply copy characters until the `null` has been copied?

Comment: You are not currently copying the '\0'. Try: `for(int j = 0; j < lengthDestination+1; j++) {...` instead; i.e., go one character more (which is the '\0').

Comment: @TanoFotang It´s just a question born from curiosity, it was just to know if it was possible to make C write that character automatically without having to prompt him to do it with that code snippet you mentioned

Comment: @Angelixus I deleted the previous comment, because it wasn't answering your question, but was instead judging why you were doing things a particular way...

Comment: @TanoFotang again, I might be wrong but, in the main function I placed a comment which specifies that the legth of that String is 15, counting the null character and that value is the one I use as "lengthDestination"

Comment: You are trying to implement `strcpy` which has no length constraint. if you want to implement `strncpy` the length constraint should be the target array, but bear in mind the rules for `strncpy` which does not always `null` terminate. Anyway you hard-coded the array length with `destinationLength = 15;` which is bad.

Comment: @Angelixus In that case, since you have guaranteed that length of source is shorter than length of destination, this should also work: `i=strlen(source); for(int j = 0; j < i+1; j++)`. that's a loop that would copy the NUL if you don't want to set the NUL explicitly in the destination. Why you dont want to use library functions, is a whole different kettle of fish.

Comment: @TanoFotang Yeah I know I could use them but, since I´m a beginner with C, I just wanted to practice doing these things that can be done with library functions doing the logic by myself.

Comment: @Angelixus In that case, always copy one character more from the source! That is the '\0';

Answer (score 1):

You will always need to 'worry' about the null terminator, in the sense that you can't *not* have a null terminator in your destination C string, and you will always need to explicitly write the null terminator at the end of your new C string.

Even the built-in `strcpy` method will copy the null terminator character from your original string to the destination string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

int copy(char * source, char * destination, unsigned int lengthDestination);

int copy(char * source, char * destination, unsigned int lengthDestination)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; source[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        destination[i] = source[i];
    }
    assert(i+1 == lengthDestination);
    destination[i+1] = '\0';
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    char * source = "Test number 17"; //Length is 15 counting the null character
    unsigned int destinationLength = 15;
    char destination[destinationLength];
    copy(source, destination, destinationLength);
    printf("The String source is: %s\n", source);
    printf("The String destination is: %s\n", destination);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The library function `strncpy` does not always place a `null` terminator in the  destination array. In that case, it is not a C string.

Comment: Yes, `strncpy` only copies the first n characters of the src string, and if the first n characters do not include a null terminator, the destination array will be left without a null terminator. 

However, `strcpy` will copy the entire source string (including the null terminator) to the destination array, assuming the destination array is large enough.

Answer (score 1):

If you are passing `destination` previously declared with *automatic storage type* or as a pointer previously allocated with `malloc`, `calloc` or `realloc` having allocated storage type, and in either case having `nchars` of storage available, you can implement a fairly robust `copy` function by simply using `snprintf`.

Since you are passing the maximum number of characters, including the *nul-terminating* character as a parameter to your `copy` function, that dovetails nicely with the `size` parameter for `snprintf`. Further, `snprintf` will insure a *nul-terminated* string in destination -- even if `source` is too long to fit in `destination`. As a benefit, `snprintf` returns the number of characters copied if there is sufficient storage in `destination` for `source`, otherwise it returns the number of characters *that would have been copied* had `destination` had sufficient space -- allowing you to determine the number of characters truncated if `destination` is insufficient to hold your `source` string.

Before looking at the implementation of `copy` let's look at a prototype and talk about declaring functions to that they provide a meaningful return, and while up to you, let's also look at the order of parameters and type qualifier for `source`, e.g.

```
/* simple strcpy src to dest, returns dest on success and number of chars
 * (including nul-termining char) in nchar, returns NULL otherwise.
 */
char *copy (char *dest, const char *src, size_t *nchar);
```

If you notice, most string functions return a pointer to the destination string on success (or `NULL` otherwise) which allows you to make immediate use of the return. Next, while not a show-stopper, most string (or memory in general) copy functions place the `destination` as the first parameter, followed later by the `source`. I'm sure either Brian Kerrigan or Dennis Ritchie could explain why, but suffice it to say, most copy function parameters are ordered that way.

Notice also that since you are not modifying the `source` string in `copy`, it is best to qualify the parameter as `const`. The `const` qualifier is more or less a promise you make to the compiler that `source` will not be modified in `copy` which allows the compiler to warn if it sees you breaking that promise, while also allowing the compiler to further optimize the function knowing `source` will not change.

Finally notice your `size` or my `nchar` is passed as a pointer above instead of an immediate value. Since a function in C can only return a single value, if you need a way to get a second piece of information back to the caller, pass a pointer as a parameter so the value at that address can be updated within the function making the new value available to the calling function. Here you return a pointer to `dest` (or `NULL`) to indicate success/failure while also updating `nchar` to contain the number of characters in `dest` (including the *nul-terminating* character as you passed in a *size* not a *length*).

The definition of `copy` is quite short and simplistic. The only requirement is the `source` and `destination` strings not overlap. (neither `strcpy` or `snprintf` are defined in that case). The basic flow is to **validate** both `src` and `dest` are not `NULL`, then handle the case where `src` is the `"empty-string"` (e.g. 1st character is the *nul-character*) and then to copy `src` to `dest` using `snprintf` saving the return in `written` and then using a simple conditional to determine whether truncation occurred (and warning in that case) and concluding by updating the value pointed to by `nchar` and returning `dest`, e.g.

```
/* simple strcpy src to dest, returns dest on success and number of chars
 * (including nul-termining char) in nchar, returns NULL otherwise.
 */
char *copy (char *dest, const char *src, size_t *nchar)
{
    if (!src || !dest) {    /* validate src & dest not NULL */
        fputs ("error: src or dest NULL\n", stderr);
        return NULL;        /* return NULL on error */
    }

    if (!*src)  /* handle src being an "empty-string" */
        *dest = 0, *nchar = 0;

    int written = snprintf (dest, *nchar, "%s", src);   /* call snprintf */

    if ((size_t)written + 1 > *nchar) { /* handle truncated case */
        fprintf (stderr, "warning: dest truncated by %zu chars.\n",
                (size_t)(written + 1) - *nchar);    /* warn with count */
    }
    else     /* src fit in dest, set nchar to no. of chars in dest */
        *nchar = (size_t)(written + 1); /* including nul-character */

    return dest;     /* return dest so available for immediate use */
}
```

Putting it altogether in a short example that takes the string to copy as the first argument to the program (using `"source string"` by default if no argument is given), you could do something like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXC 16     /* constant for destination length */

/* simple strcpy src to dest, returns dest on success and number of chars
 * (including nul-termining char) in nchar, returns NULL otherwise.
 */
char *copy (char *dest, const char *src, size_t *nchar)
{
    if (!src || !dest) {    /* validate src & dest not NULL */
        fputs ("error: src or dest NULL\n", stderr);
        return NULL;        /* return NULL on error */
    }

    if (!*src)  /* handle src being an "empty-string" */
        *dest = 0, *nchar = 0;

    int written = snprintf (dest, *nchar, "%s", src);   /* call snprintf */

    if ((size_t)written + 1 > *nchar) { /* handle truncated case */
        fprintf (stderr, "warning: dest truncated by %zu chars.\n",
                (size_t)(written + 1) - *nchar);    /* warn with count */
    }
    else     /* src fit in dest, set nchar to no. of chars in dest */
        *nchar = (size_t)(written + 1); /* including nul-character */

    return dest;     /* return dest so available for immediate use */
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char *src = argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "source string",
        dest[MAXC];
    size_t n = MAXC;

    if (copy (dest, src, &n))
        printf ("dest: '%s' (%zu chars including nul-char)\n", dest, n);
}
```

(**note:** the maximum number of characters in `dest` is kept short intentionally to easily show how truncation is handled -- size as appropriate for your needs)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/strcpy_snprintf
dest: 'source string' (14 chars including nul-char)
```

Showing maximum number of characters that can be copied without warning:

```
$ ./bin/strcpy_snprintf  123456789012345
dest: '123456789012345' (16 chars including nul-char)
```

Showing handling source too long for destination:

```
$ ./bin/strcpy_snprintf  1234567890123456
warning: dest truncated by 1 chars.
dest: '123456789012345' (16 chars including nul-char)
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions. There are at least a dozen different ways to approach a string copy, but given you are passing `dest` with its own storage and passing the maximum number of characters (including the *nul-character*) as a parameter, it's hard to beat `snprintf` in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way:

```
char *copy(const char *source, char *destination, size_t lengthDestination)
{
    memcpy(destination, source, lengthDestination -1);
    destination[lengthDestination -1] = 0;
    return destination;
}
```